# jQuery binding events to elements with dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dynamic

I have a trigger element and a responding element.

```
<div class="more"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
```

I would like to bind an open/close type event.

```
$('.more').delegate($('.more'), 'click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('more');
    $(this).addClass('less');
    $(this).text("less...");
    $('.info').addClass("open");
});

$('.less').delegate($('.less'), 'click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('more');
    $(this).removeClass('less');
    $(this).text("more...");
    $('.info').removeClass("open");
});
```

It doesn't work as intended, if the second function is nested in the first then you can open and close only once.
If the script is formatted sensibly as above it will open but not close.

Could anyone help me out?
Bonus if the script could support the .info could be either a sibling or the element immediately following $(.more/.less)'s parent.

I've been toying with .on/.live/.bind but less successfully than above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use JavaScript to toggle a class, and let CSS magic do the rest. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/69sX5/1/

And here is the code:

HTML

```
<div>
    Some visible content
</div>

<div class="content-fold">
    <div class="more">More...</div>
    <div class="less">Less...</div>
</div>
<div class="info">Some hidden additional content</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Additional content and Less button hidden by default */
.content-fold + .info, .content-fold .less {
    display: none;
}

/* Additional content and Less button shown when class shown is active */
.content-fold.shown + .info, .content-fold.shown .less {
    display: block;
}
/* More button hidden when additional content is shown */
.content-fold.shown .more {
    display: none;
}

/*
You can also move the "div.info" into the "div.content-fold",
and use ".content-fold.shown > .info" instead of ".content-fold.shown + .info"

Browser support is quite good for adjacent selector (see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#t11 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors#Browser_compatibility)
*/
```

JavaScript

```
$('.content-fold').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('shown');
});
```

Comment: I almost dismissed this but there's some subtle cunning in here.
Not an exact fit as, to complicate things there may also be an element in between .content-fold and .info but I am playing around with this to see if I can adapt it.

Comment: Once I put this in and tweaked it for the specific site it worked a treat.
Wasn't (initially) too keen on adding to the DOM but given due consideration this is a really smart solution.

Comment: I'm glad you like it and solved your problem :) I just wanted to bring an alternative to JavaScript centric solutions, and reduce the amount of JavaScript needed as little as possible. But for sure this code can be adapter to others situations (the `div`s can be moved arround etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Use event **[delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** ,and binded to document or immediate parent,not same element

```
$(document).on( 'click',".more", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('more');
    $(this).addClass('less');
    $(this).text("less...");
    $('.info').addClass("open");
});

$(document).on('click',".less", function(){
    $(this).addClass('more');
    $(this).removeClass('less');
    $(this).text("more...");
    $('.info').removeClass("open");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/52/)

NOTE: delegate was outdated with latest version of jquery ,so use **on** instead,
**ISSUE**: you are delegated with same element  `$('.less'),$('.more')` use immediate `parent` or document

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply and the demo.
Something strange is going on my end. Demo works fine obviously.Possibly our jQuery version (1.10.2)?

As is I'm seeing that the call to .text is clearing the document, no DOM at all.

Removing the text() calls just to see and I get what I had originally which is the div will open but not close and the link retains class "more" and does not get class "less".

It looks like this function underwent some changes as afaict $(this) equates to $(document)

Comment: tried adding:
    var eSrc = $(arguments[0].target);
to replace $(this) but it seems both functions are firing on click :(

what's wierder is that if I remove the function I'm trying to bind to .less (and console.log(eSrc) for good measure) then I see that the open happens as expected but the function continues to respond to clicks on .less

Answer (score 0):

Use id to do your task. it's easy.
Html

```
<div class="more" id="toggle"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
   var $this = $(this) //store object
   if($this.hasClass('more')) {
      $this.removeClass('more').addClass('less').text('Less...')
      $this.next('.info').addClass('open');
   } else {
      $this.removeClass('less').addClass('more').text('More...')
      $this.next('.info').removeClass('open');
   }
});
```

js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/53/

Comment: Relying on an ID will restrict the script to single use per page, there are cases where I have 4 or 5 of them. :(